# Understanding an identity for an linear, self-adjoint operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the pde
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}y(x,t)=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}y(x,t)~~(*)
$$
with homogeneous boundary conditions
$$
y(0,t)=0=y(1,t).
$$
Let $\langle u,v\rangle=\int_0^1 u(x)v(x)\, dx$.
Here, we have the linear, self-adjoint Sturm-Liouville operator
$$
L=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}
$$
Hence, there is the eigenvalue problem
$$
L\Phi=-k^2\Phi
$$
where the eigenfunctions $\Phi_n$ form an orthonormal basis of $L^2(0,1)$ and are given by
$$
\Phi_n(x)=\sqrt{2}\sin(n\pi x).
$$
So, we know that
$$
y(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\langle y,\Phi_n\rangle\Phi_n.~~(**)
$$
It remains to determine $\langle y,\Phi_n\rangle$.

> > It is said that plugging $(**)$ into $(*)$, we have
> >     $$
> > \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\langle y,\Phi_n\rangle \Phi_n\right)=\sum_{n=1}\langle Ly,\Phi_n\rangle \Phi_n.~~(***)
> > $$
> >     I cannot see the right-hand side of this identity.

When I plug it into the right-hand side of $(*)$ and using the linearity of $L$, I only get 
$$
Ly=L\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\langle y,\Phi_n\rangle \Phi_n\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}L\left(\langle y,\Phi_n\rangle \Phi_n\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\langle y,\Phi_n\rangle L\Phi_n.
$$
Maybe it is
$$
\langle y,\Phi_n\rangle L\Phi_n=\langle Ly,\Phi_n\rangle\Phi_n?
$$

Comment: Shouldn't $t$ be present on the right side of ($**$)?

Comment: That wouldnt make sense according to the definition you have of <u,v>. I need more context to answer but, under these conditions if you do what Tao does here. Go down to Theorem 7 and further where he says "We introduce a new inner product...". Under that your result follows like his result. You need a L strictly positive. Please check: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/the-spectral-theorem-and-its-converses-for-unbounded-symmetric-operators/

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to expand a function of $t$ in $x$, the coefficients must be allowed to vary in $t$. That is,
$$
                y(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n(t)\Phi_n(x)
$$
You you end up with an ODE for the coefficients
\begin{align}
      \frac{\partial}{\partial t}y(x,t)&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n}'(t)\Phi_{n}(x) \\
   \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}y(x,y)& =\sum_{n=1}C_n(t)(-n^2\pi^2\Phi_n(x))
\end{align}
Equating the two series gives
$$
                   C_n'(t)=-n^2\pi^2C_n(t) \\
                    C_n(t) = C_n(0)e^{-n^2\pi^2 t}
$$
The initial data then gives $C_n(0)$. That is, starting with
$$
            y(x,0) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n(0)\Phi_{n}(x),
$$
you multiply both sides by $\Phi_m(x)$, integrate over $[0,1]$, assume you can interchange summation and integration, and obtain
$$
        \int_{0}^{1}y(x,0)\Phi_{n}(x)dx = C_n(0)
$$
Finally,
$$
      y(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{1}y(x',0)\Phi_{n}(x')dx'\right)e^{-n^2\pi^2 t}\Phi_{n}(x).
$$
There are convergence issues to address, especially in $C[0,1]$, where $y(x,0)$ will need to be periodic on $[0,1]$ and smooth, or of bounded variation, etc..